# Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700). Make sure you do not have another instance of DDM

Tags: java, android, adb, ddms

I have tried every tip to solve this problem but it simply do not work. The problem accured after update of android studio to 3.01 + gradle. I have older dependencies and gradle + android studio on my laptop and it works without any problem. I just want get access to Android device monitor to look up into my sqlite database files.

I tried simply kill, restart adb process, use different port then 8701, edit host file but without any progress into resolving this issue.

Everything except Device monitor works fine. I am able to launch application on emulator and actual phone. Maybe someone met this issue after updating program and have some sort of magic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found a problem earlier but forgot to post it here. It appears to be a issue with platform level 24 and above. You need to work on level 23 in order to use android device monitor.